# Selecting form based on ID

Tags: perl, mechanize, web-scraping

For testing purposes I am trying to write a script using WWW::Mechanize that would login to Gowalla via https://api.gowalla.com/signin

As I can see the login form does not have a "name" attribute but it has an "id" attribute.
Mech has a "submit_form" method that can get the name as a parameter but I don't see it accepting the id as a parameter.

So would that be then

```
$w->form_id('form_signin');
$w->submit_form(
fields => {
    username => $username,
    user_session_password => $password,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've selected the form via id attribute, but that doesn't allow you to use id attribute to select fields, this should fix your code:

```
$w->submit_form(
fields => {
    user_session[username] => $username,
    user_session[username] => $password,
});
```

If you get an error, enclose the field names in single quotes, not sure whether the square brackets will be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

WWW::Mechanize sets the focus onto the single form automatically. You can submit it with $m->click('') or $m->submit();